# ASP.NET MVC method NotFound

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет. есть следующий метод

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AttachFile(int operationId)
{
    var _operation = _operationService.GetOperationById(operationId);
    foreach (string file in Request.Files)
    {
        var upload = Request.Files[file];
        if (upload != null)
        {
            var attachedFile = new AttachedFile()
            {
                OriginalName = upload.FileName,
                NewName = upload.FileName,
                RootDirectory = _operation.GetDirectory(),
                Stream = upload.InputStream
            };
                _fileWorking.SaveFile(attachedFile);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { operationId = operationId });
}
```

Данный метод используется в следующем представлении:

```
@model  IEnumerable<CSCP.Core.Domain.AttachedFiles.AttachedFileListModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        Layout = null;
    }
 }
 <div id="tabAttachment">
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Update", "Index", "Attachment", new { operationId = ViewBag.OperationId },
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tabAttachment" }, new { @id = "ActionLink", @role = "presentation", @style = "visibility:hidden;" })

<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="file" name="upload" id="uploadFile" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="button" id="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-default" data-operationid="@ViewBag.OperationId" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@Html.Partial("_AttachmentFilesList", Model)
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/attachment")
```

Код скрипта:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var files = document.getElementById('uploadFile').files;
        if (files.length > 0) {
            if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                var data = new FormData();
                for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
                    data.append("file" + x, files[x]);
                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Attachment/AttachFile?operationId=" + $('#submit').attr('data-operationId'),
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: data,
                    success: function () { $("#ActionLink").click(); },
                    error: function () { $("#ActionLink").click(); }
                });
            } else {
                alert("Браузер не поддерживает загрузку файлов HTML5!");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

При запуске приложения на локальной машине все работает.файлы сохраняются. После публикации приложения на сервер метод не срабатывает. Запустил отладку в браузере и вижу следующую ошибку:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://10.5.0.253/Attachment/AttachFile?operationId=154"

Не пойму, почему так?

Comment: А публикуете вы свое приложение по какому пути?

Comment: физический путь до сайта выглядит так: "C:\WWW\MyWebApplication\"

Comment: Зачем мне физический путь? Лучше виртуальный путь скажите.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov большое спасибо за подсказку. проблема была решена, суть не внимательность: было так url: "/Attachment/AttachFile?operationId=" + $('#submit').attr('data-operationId'),а надо было "/CSCP/Attachment/AttachFile?operationId=" + $('#submit').attr('data-operationId')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, так, как вы предложили в комментарии, делать не нужно.

Проблема в виртуальном пути. Но просто захардкодить другой путь - неправильно! Ведь приложение может быть установлено по любому пути.

Для правильного получения виртуального пути к действию следует воспользоваться хелпером `Url`:

```
url: "@Url.Action("AttachFile", "Attachment")?operationId=" + $('#submit').attr('data-operationId')
```

Способ выше подойдет, если ваш скрипт находится в `.cshtml`-файле. Но есть лучший способ, к тому же работающий всегда. Можно передать нужный путь через атрибут любого из элементов. В вашем случае красивее всего будет передать url там же, где сейчас передается `operationId`:

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-default" data-url="@Url.Action("AttachFile", "Attachment", new { operationId = ViewBag.OperationId})" />


url: this.dataset.url,
```